# Redirecting my images hosted on another website to specific pages when clicked using htaccess

Tags: php, image, .htaccess, hotlinking, redirect

Basically, I wan't to redirect images that people click on to a specific URL, as an example.

http://mydomain.com/upload/39248928434.jpg

once that image is clicked from a forum or where ever somebody linked it, I want it to return to this URL instead of the above.

http://mydomain.com/phpscript.php?image=39248928434.jpg

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the image will exist at http://mydomain.com/upload/39248928434.jpg, and by "clicking" on the image the intention is that their browser should be directed to that address...

I haven't tested this code out, but here's a slight modification to some code I found ([here](http://www.besthostratings.com/articles/prevent-hot-linking.html)) to disable hot linking using mod_rewrite that may do what you're looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^$

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www.)?mydomain.com/.*$ [NC]

RewriteRule upload/(.*\.jpg)$ /phpscript?image=$1
```

I'm not entirely sure that that gets you 100% there, as I'm not sure how the referrer is recorded when they click through from some other site and land on your page.  But this should point you in the right direction at least.

Edit: removed the [F] flag, as it returns a "Forbidden" response

Comment: that doesnt change the redirect URL when you click the image :C

Comment: You want the actual, user facing URL to change?  Add the [R] directive after the rewriterule: RewriteRule upload/(.*\.jpg)$ /phpscript?image=$1 [R]

Comment: I want the user to be able to paste the image file normally onto another website, but when they click the actual image, THEN its redirected to the changed link... atm it doesnt seem to work.

Comment: I am using

#redirect
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www.)?miscupload.com/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule /?([^.]+\.(gif|jpe?g|png))$ /pagination1.php?image=$1


at the moment it doesnt display the image, though it does redirect to the link i want, for some reason it wont display the image though... which i want it to before it redirects to the link.

Comment: Does it display the image on the other site OK?  It's just when you direct the browser specifically at the image that the problem occurs?  Have you checked your Apache error logs to see what it's requesting?

Comment: no, it doesnt display on the other websites correctly, everything else is working fine though, it redirects to the right link and what not.

Comment: Gotcha.  When I look closer at the code you posted, the ! in each of the RewriteCond lines negates them, and should cause the RewriteRule to only apply to other sites, not your own... basically, it should either be redirecting off site, or on site, but not both, and from what you've said, it sounds like it's definitely redirecting off site and thus breaking those images.

Comment: dont know what you mean, ill play around with it more though.